# post method how to send only required parameters objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipartform-data, afhttprequestoperation

I am sending multipart data to server text along with images and voice/image and voice are optional in this case when i am not sending the image data or voice the app is crashing please help on this !

```
-(void)uploadphoto{
 NSString* mid= @"1";
    NSString*userid=@"13"; //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kUserID];

    imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (thumbnail.image);

     AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURLString]];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"UserID":userid, @"Name": name_TF.text,@"MandalID":mid,@"Address":address_TV.text,@"PinCode":pincode_TF.text,@"Email":emailid_TF.text,@"Dese":grivence_TV.text};

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"Grievance/CreateRequest" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:audioData name:@"file" fileName:@"Audio.m4a" mimeType:@"audio/.mp4 .m4a"];

    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
    }];
    [op start];

    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to get the error please update the error then will rectify easly. may be the dictionary of some key will nil. so the crash will appear.

Comment: yes @HariKrishnan.P is right but if the dictionary of some key is not nill then my code will work check my answer :)

Comment: the error is "body contain in valid parameters" it showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"Grievance/CreateRequest" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {  

  if (imageData!=nil) 
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];


    if (audioData!=nil) 
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:audioData name:@"file" fileName:@"Audio.m4a" mimeType:@"audio/.mp4 .m4a"];

} success:^ ...
```

In case of while you not send image or audio your imagedata & audiodata contains nil ( you can't send image or audio which have nil data).

Answer (score 0):

Set bool according to your request

```
 -(void)uploadphoto{

    BOOL isImgData = YES; //set according to avaibility
    BOOL isVoiceData = YES;//set according to avaibility

     NSString* mid= @"1";
        NSString*userid=@"13"; //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kUserID];

        imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation (thumbnail.image);

         AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURLString]];

        NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"UserID":userid, @"Name": name_TF.text,@"MandalID":mid,@"Address":address_TV.text,@"PinCode":pincode_TF.text,@"Email":emailid_TF.text,@"Dese":grivence_TV.text};

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"Grievance/CreateRequest" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    if(isImgData){

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"file" fileName:@"image.png" mimeType:@"image/png"];
    }

    if(isVoiceData){

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:audioData name:@"file" fileName:@"Audio.m4a" mimeType:@"audio/.mp4 .m4a"];

    }
        } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
        }];
        [op start];

        }
}
```

Comment: you can chnge if condition according to your requirement !!